# Make PandasAI retain context

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, azure, azure-openai

I am working on PandasAI and want to retain the context to what I asked and what it responded to continue the contextual conversation.

Tried a few things but it takes every query as a new standalone query.

Reference Code - https://pypi.org/project/pandasai/

Is there any way to retain the context and continue the conversation?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can implement this use langchain https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain.
2. since pandasai is opensource, you can check and modify the code to implement this